# Which the best way to write our controller, dao and service in spring framework?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

For example, We have a model `Product` and the web page can insert a product and return all product in one request.

The ways below Which the best way to write our controller, dao and service? and Why?

A:

```
@Repository
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ...{
   @Override
   public List<Product> findAll(){
       // return all product
   }
   @Override
   public void insert(Product product){
       // just insert a product
   }
}

@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ...{
   @Autowired
   private ProductDao dao;

   @Override
   public List<Product> insertAndFindAll(Product product){
       dao.insert(product);
       return dao.findAll();
   }
}

@Controller
public class ProductController{
    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping(...)
    public @ResponseBody List<Product> insertAndFindAll(@RequestBody Product product){
        return productService.insertAndFindAll(product);
    }
}
```

B:

```
@Repository
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ...{
   @Override
   public List<Product> findAll(){
       // return all product
   }
   @Override
   public void insert(Product product){
       // just insert a product
   }
}

@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ...{
   @Autowired
   private ProductDao dao;

   @Override
   public List<Product> findAll(){
       return dao.findAll();
   }
   @Override
   public void insert(Product product){
       dao.insert(product);
   }
}

@Controller
public class ProductController{
    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping(...)
    public @ResponseBody List<Product> insertAndFindAll(@RequestBody Product product){
        productService.insert(product);
        return productService.findAll(product);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the logic relates only to the user interface, it belongs into presentation layer (controller). If it is a core business logic, it belongs to service layer.

In your example, finding all products is likely independent on the insert and is only done because you want to display list of products once the new product is inserted. So that is a UI thing and belongs to controller.

If the two steps were e.g. to update the quantity of product stored and to insert an order, that would belong to service layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering about applying transaction manager in your service layer then I think it will be a good practice to separate out the `insert` and `findAll` methods of `service` as both operations are different. So considering this approach in `B` is better than in `A`.

One more thing about your design, you can and I think you should separate out the `findAll` request from the `insert` request from Client side.
 You can redirect to other Request mapping which handles the request only for `findAll`.

In both approaches mentioned above will make it clear that each of your controller method handle a unique request and will be a better design.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to go with option B, although I would suggest a small change in the controller. 

The *"Controller"* in the option B can have two methods, one that inserts a product and one that finds all products. The *"insertProduct"* method would return a path such as *"findAll"* which matches RequestMapping on *"findAllProducts"* method.